# Is it possible to upload to Drive using the Save to Drive button from a website canvas?

Tags: file-upload, html5-canvas, google-drive-api

I developed a JavaScript application for editing photo. I would like to know if I can use the Save to Drive button for uploading the result image from a canvas to Google Drive ( without any server).